# Android widget refresh not working

Tags: android, widget, alarm

My widget should refresh its textviews every day at 0:00. In the widget_provider.xml I set android:updatePeriodMillis="1000" but I read that the minimum update period is 30 minutes and I have to use alarmManager for this. So i want an alarm that triggers the refresh every day at 0:00. UpdateService.class handles the refreshing (setting texts for textviews based on date. The class is just not called until around half an hour after midnight)

In the `public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)` method I am using this code:

```
 Intent intentN = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentN, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 Calendar calendarN = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendarN.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
 calendarN.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
 calendarN.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 44);
 calendarN.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendarN.getTimeInMillis(), 7000, pendingIntent);
```

*(I am trying with actual time now)*

Is this the right place for this code? Why doesn't it work? I am using toast messages in UpdateService.java, but i never get the toast in the `onStart(Intent intent, int startId)` method apart from the first time, when the app in installed.

Thanks in advance

**Update**

With the help of probablykevin, i rewrite the code. I tried this code out in an Activity and it works:

```
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UpdateService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

                 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                 alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                 calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                 calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
                 alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 8000, pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

However if I modify it for the AppWidgetProvider class (and put it there ofc) it does not work. I never even get the toast msg:

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, myIntent, 0);

                  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                  alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                  Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                  calendar2.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                  calendar2.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
                  alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar2.getTimeInMillis(), 8000, pendingIntent);
         Toast.makeText(context, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your repeating time should be 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, as it is in milliseconds.
Second your start time could be found using the time left until the next 0:00:

```
final long MILLIS_IN_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
long timeUntilMidnight = MILLIS_IN_DAY - (System.currentTimeMillis() % MILLIS_IN_DAY);
```

Then set your alarm by adding the time left to the current time:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(...System.currentTimeMillis() + timeUntilMidnight, MILLIS_IN_DAY...);
```

Make sure you don't set multiple of the same alarm. I like to call

```
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

before setting it again just to be sure.

Comment: The frequency was 7000 ms to test the repeating. I updated the main post with your code. Not working..

Comment: However, I ran a toast on timeUntilMidnight, and it says that midnight will be in 1:47 (6212436ms), which means at 2 AM (now here it is 12:13 AM).

Comment: I'm sorry it hasn't worked yet. Is the problem now just with the time? or does the service have yet to fire at all.

Comment: The problem must be with the last line. I set the alarm to         alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, 5000, pendingIntent);
but it is never fired.

Comment: I also tried a one-time alarm:  alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendarN.getTimeInMillis()+ 10 * 1000, pendingIntent); but this does not work either. Is it possible, that the onUpdate method of the AppWidgetProvider is called every 30 minutes? Because UpdateService.java is called every 30 minutes. Maybe this whole alarm code is in the wrong place. But where should I place it?

Comment: Are you checking your logcat for any errors or warnings? Try setting a flag for the PendingIntent `PendingIntent.getService(..., PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);` Also, Log some text just before the alarm command and see if it is being run at all.